# Question about Vulkan Initialization / Deinitialization and Android App life cycle event

Tags: android, vulkan

I have studied on Vulkan sample applications provided by numbers of platform venders (Qucomm Adreno SDK, PowerVR SDK, ARM Mali SDK and Google's android NDK samples) for quite a while. I noticed that all samples performe Vulkan initialization and de-initialization in the following code pattern:

```
void android_main(struct android_app* androidApp)
{
    ...
    androidApp->onAppCmd = [](struct android_app* androidApp, int32_t cmd) -> void //Event handle (Lambda)
    {
        VulkanApp* app = (VulkanApp*)androidApp->userData;
        switch (cmd) 
        {
        case APP_CMD_INIT_WINDOW:   
            initVulkan(...);    //Initialize vulkan: layers, extension, instance, surface, device, swapchain, ...
            break;
        case APP_CMD_TERM_WINDOW:
            deinitVulkan(...);    //Deinitialize vulkan: in reversed order...
            break;
        ...
        }
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Basically app initializes Vulkan components in NDK event **APP_CMD_INIT_WINDOW** and destroy them in event **APP_CMD_TERM_WINDOW**. This code is quite reasonable when app is launched by use, runs for a while and then is quit by user.

---

However, when users swap android app into background (by home or menu button) and then bring it back for several times, paired events **APP_CMD_TERM_WINDOW** and **APP_CMD_INIT_WINDOW** will be triggered for several times and thus the function **initVulkan()** and **deinitVulkan()** will be called for several times.

**Under this scenario the code appear to be unreasonable to me though:** since the app is just temporarily pushed to background and brought back to foreground, why should we destroy all Vulkan components like layers, extension, instance, device, surface, swapchain, pipeline ... and recreate them all over? At most, perhaps the only components may need to be recreated are swapchain and pipeline. But why all SDK's samples app performe this heavy recreation?

By the way, when I compare with Vulkan sample source code on other platforms, like Windows, Linux, macOS and iOS, none of them performe such heavy recreations.

I have tried to use a **"initialize once"** solution but android app crashes when it was brought back to foreground from background.

**So may question is:**  Do we have to destroy and recreate all Vulkan components when Android app swapped between background and foreground? If not, how can we do it?

### -----

**UPDATE:** 
I have received few kind suggestions about my question and I understand during the "swapped-away" period of Android apps, we better limit system resource held by app (particularly when receiving low-memory warning), and meanwhile, a fine-grained pause/resume mechanism on Vulkan components can help to keep good balance between light memory usage and quick app resumption.

I took a review on Google NDK OpenGL ES "teapot" sample and I noticed that this NDK gl sample uses highly find tuned mechanism to pause / resume OpenGL context:
At event handling part, the code looks like:

```
    switch (cmd)
    {
        case APP_CMD_INIT_WINDOW:
            // The window is being shown, get it ready.
            if (app->window != NULL)
                eng->InitDisplay(app);
            break;
        case APP_CMD_TERM_WINDOW:
            // The window is being hidden or closed, clean it up.
            eng->TermDisplay();
            break;
        case APP_CMD_LOW_MEMORY:
            // Free up GL resources
            eng->TrimMemory();
            break;
```

And this is code of function InitDisplay():

```
int Engine::InitDisplay(android_app *app)
{
    if (!initialized_resources_)  // THIS IS FIRST TIME THE EVENT IS TRIGGERED WHEN APP IS LAUNCHED
    {
        gl_context_->Init(app_->window);    //Initialize OpenGL
        LoadResources();
        ...
    }
    else  // TRIGGERED WHEN APP IS BROUGHT BACK FROM BACKGROUND TO FOREGROUND
    {
        // On some devices, ANativeWindow is re-created when the app is resumed
        if (app->window != gl_context_->GetANativeWindow())
        {
            // Re-initialize ANativeWindow.
            assert(gl_context_->GetANativeWindow());
            UnloadResources();
            gl_context_->Invalidate();
            gl_context_->Init(app->window); //Initialize OpenGL again
            LoadResources();
            ...
        }
        // Normal case, only need to resume OpenGL
        else
        {
            // initialize OpenGL ES and EGL
            if (EGL_SUCCESS == gl_context_->Resume(app_->window))//Resume OpenGL
            {
                UnloadResources();
                LoadResources();
            }
            ...
        }
    }
    ...
```

As we can see from the code, under most of "good cases", only small part of OpenGL resources are unloaded and reloaded; only under "bad cases", OpenGL context is fully destroyed and recreated, this can generate quick app resumption.

**So my question can be extended to :** Does any one know a good Vulkan/Android template app that use this find-grined Vulkan pause / resume mechanism? Or would like to share your own code to do this? I'm currently working on this but not going very well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible to keep most of Vulkan around when in the background, but you're right that you'll have to re-create the swapchain (and any dependent objects, like image views for the swapchain images) since you get a new native window/surface when brought back to the foreground. Unfortunately I don't have any sample code to point you at.

Existing samples probably did it this way for simplicity, since on most other platforms there isn't a need to support swapchains that have a different lifetime to the rest of the top-level Vulkan objects.

It's actually recommended to not discard too much memory immediately when going into the background. But if you don't, you should pay attention to the [onTrimMemory](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html#onTrimMemory(int)) callback, and release any large data when you get that. That allows you to restore quickly (and without burning power reloading textures etc.) if the user switches away briefly, but still allows the system to reclaim the memory without completely killing your app if needed.

Comment: Thanks Jesse, I have started making this app pause/resume handling more fine-grained than those sample apps. I think the equivalent NDK event to java "onTrimMemory()" should be APP_CMD_LOW_MEMORY, this is one related event exposed by NDK glue.

Comment: I updated my question after I took review on Google's OpenGL sample app, which provide fine-tuned OpenGL context pause / resume mechanism. Personally, I think Google Vulkan sample apps should provide similar fine-tuned mechanism. Even consider sample's simplicity intention, it will be better for Vulkan beginners to learn how to do Vulkan resource management.

Answer (score 2):

> Under this scenario the code appear to be unreasonable to me though:
>   since the app is just temporarily pushed to background and brought
>   back to foreground, why should we destroy all Vulkan components ...

Define "temporary". A typical user may have dozens of applications opened but idle and running in the background, and if they all hold on to all their resources that's a massive consumer of memory.

Applications using a graphics API is nearly always a heavy user of memory, so it is reasonable to expect backgrounded applications to free up resources for the foreground application to use.

> By the way, when I compare with Vulkan sample source code on other
>   platforms, like Windows, Linux, macOS and iOS, none of them perform
>   such heavy recreations.

iOS doesn't force it, but it is highly recommended in developer best practice that an application frees memory heavy resources as part of the `applicationDidEnterBackground` handler.

The rest are desktop platforms where the application usage model is completely different (open -> close, not open -> suspend), so it's not surprising that they have a different programming model.

Comment: Tanks Solidpixel, I understand all your suggestions. I'll extend my question a bit further by editing the question again (extent it by comment here is not convenient). There are still something not quite clear for me though.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to several suggestion I have been given and also [this article at Gamasutra](https://www.gamasutra.com/blogs/JohannesKuhlmann/20171016/307643/Bringing_Galaxy_on_Fire_3_to_Vulkan_Vulkan_on_Android.php), I have made everything clear and have finally got the perfect solution for Vulkan resource management during app suspension and resumption.

**The basic idea is:**  there is no need to recreate all Vulkan resources again after app resumed from suspension. Doing this will cause all Vulkan related app resources recreated and is very hard to code. Only the following Vulkan objects needs to be recreated:

- Surface
- RenderPass
- Swapchain & related

The NDK event handling code should look like:

```
 switch (cmd)
    {
        case APP_CMD_INIT_WINDOW:
            if( this is triggered by app launch)
                initVulkan();
            else //This is triggered by app resumption
                resetVulkan(); // recreateSurface, RenderPass, Swapchain and related
            break;
            ...
```

My Vulkan app now can swap itself in and out very smoothly.